# matplotlib get_window_extent() gets wrong text height

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, macos-sierra

In the code below I'm using `get_window_extent()` to get the height of a text label. I have set the figure dpi value to 72 dpi in an attempt to make the screen display and font size have a 1:1 relationship. My expectation is that the value retrieved by `get_window_extent()` would match the text point size value.

To test this out I created a loop to draw a set of text labels of increasing size and I'm finding that the value retrieved by `get_window_extent()` matches for some font sizes but not for others.

Here is the output produced by the code below:

```
Font Size
Set Returned
9   9.0
10  10.0
11  10.0
12  13.0
13  13.0
14  14.0
15  15.0
16  15.0
17  18.0
18  18.0
```

It appears that either the figure dpi setting is not actually at 72 dpi, or that something is amiss with the `get_window_extent()` method.

I'm running Matplotlib 1.5.0 on macOS 10.12.5, using the WXagg backend. Any ideas as why this is occurring would be welcome.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('wxagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# points per inch
points_per_inch = 72

# set figure size in inches
myfsize = (8, 6)

# create figure and subplot axes matrix
myfig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, dpi=72, figsize=myfsize)

# adjust subplot spacing
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.04, hspace=0.04, right=0.8,
                    bottom=0.1, top=0.9, left=0.125)

# draw canvase to get positions
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()

string = 'curve'

print
print 'Font Size'
print 'Set', '\t', 'Returned'

# loop over a range of font sizes and print retrieved font size
for i in range(10):
    text_size = 9 + i
    text_position = i / 10.0
    txt = ax.text(0.0, text_position, string, fontsize=text_size,
                  transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    txt_height_display = txt.get_window_extent().height
    print text_size, '\t', txt_height_display

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the discretization of the text onto screen pixels, there may always be a deviation between the number of pixels filled by the font and the fontsize. This deviation may be up tp 2 pixels - one to each side.
I therefore wouldn't be worried or supprised by the results you get.

Comment: Thanks, I plotted two identical text strings at the same position in two colors at point sizes of 17 and 18 and observed the heights were identical on the screen (widths were different).